# Query que seleciona última linha de cada dispositivo?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho 3 tabelas no meu DB:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `local` (
  `codigo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IMEI` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`codigo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2323 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dispositivos` (
  `codigo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IMEI` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `client` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`codigo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clientes` (
  `codigo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `numero_cliente` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `login` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`codigo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Clientes tem dispositivos que mandam mensagens de sua localização (com a data do próprio dispositivo, por isso não ordeno a tabela pela data).

Todas as tabelas são ordenadas pelo campo `auto_increment`.

Eu gostaria de saber como pegar a última linha da tabela `local` de cada dispositivo para um dado cliente.

Por exemplo:

Cliente 1000 tem os dispositivos:

- 111222333444555
- 222333444555666
- 333444555666777

Eu quero pegar a última linha de `111222333444555`, mais a última linha de `222333444555666` e a última linha de `333444555666777`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não pude testar o código, fiz "de cabeça". Veja se faz aquilo que você deseja:

```
select l.*
from
(
select d.imei, max(l.codigo) cod_local
from clientes c
join dispositivos d on d.client = c.codigo
join local l on l.imei = d.imei
where c.codigo = :param_cod_cli
group by d.imei
) aux_tab
join local l on l.codigo = aux_tab.cod_local
```

Comment: Funcionou, valeu! Tu foi o quarto que me respondeu (contando outros lugares) e o único que funcionou. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Fico contente. Abraço!